# How to get lock of complete table in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have a requirement to get lock on the complete table,is it possible?

I tried like following but it doesn't work for me-

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();  

session.lock(Product.class, LockMode.UPGRADE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(); 
Product product = (Product) session.get(PageInfo.class,1,LockMode.UPGRADE);
```

Make your product class serializable.

```
public class Product implements Serializable{

   //your variables and getter/setters
```

The following code is working just tested.Cheers

Comment: it doesn't work it throws exception.              org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class org.hibernate.LockMode

Comment: I think hibernate Session doesn't have method of type-----                  public Object get(Class type, LockMode lm)

Comment: Product p = (Product) session.get(Product.class,00.LockMode.UPGRADE);

Comment: this doesn't throws exception but not getting lock on complete table.

Comment: For that is your Product class mapped with the entire table??

Comment: Try this one..Updated

Comment: Did you get it working..I have updated the code and tested on my own database.

Comment: I added serialVersionUID and tried but it doesn't work, it throws exception--------org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.Long

Comment: Try with 1 not 1L